# How to find the probability that we need to weigh at least 20 eggs before we find the 12th medium-sized egg

Tags: probability, statistics

> The mass of eggs in a farm is normally distributed with a mean of $575~\text{g}$ and standard deviation of $80~\text{g}$.
>
> (a) An egg can be classified as having a “medium size” if its mass is between
>    $500$ and $600$ grams. What is the probability that a randomly selected egg from the farm is a medium-sized egg? Use R to find the answer.
>
> (b) Let $M$ be the count of medium-sized eggs in a random sample of $100$. What is the distribution of $M$? Using R, find the probability that at least half of the $100$ eggs are medium-sized.
>
> (c) Eggs from this farm are sold by the dozen (12 eggs). Let $D$ be the number of randomly selected eggs we must weigh until we find the 12th medium-sized egg. What is the distribution of $D$ ? Using R, find the probability that we need to weigh at least 20 eggs before we find the 12th medium-sized egg

My attempt using Rstudio for a and b

p <- pnorm(600,575,80)-pnorm(500,575,80)

p

[1] 0.448419

sum(dbinom(50:100, 50, p))

[1] 3.838845e-18

Now for part c do you use the part b and change 50 to 12 to find the distribution and then somehow find the probability using that to find the second part of part c?

$$EDIT$$

Possible answer to part C, by
$$P(X=10) = {20-1 \choose 12-1}0.0448419^{12}(1-0.044819)^{20-12}$$

Thoughts?

Comment: Part A seems okay, it's correct. For part C, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Negative_binomial_distribution

Comment: Is Part B okay you think? Because I need that for part C right?

Comment: hmmm I don't see a reason why you'd need the result of B in order to calculate C. You just need to take eggs until you have 12 medium-sized ones. So that's calculating the number of trials until 12 successes. You just need to calculat the probability of a success in this case and then apply the Negative Binomial distribution.

Comment: @MattiP. Is that the answer, I have just edited the post?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The result for (**a**) is right.

At (**b**) it seems that you haven´t used the right number for $p=0.448419$ like at (c).

$$P(X\geq 50)=\sum_{k=50}^{100} {{100} \choose k} \cdot  0.448419^k\cdot (1-0.448419)^{100-k}$$

$=0.1744=17.44\%$

At **(c)** the key word is "at least". You have to sum from $n=20$ to infinity.

$$\sum_{n=20}^{\infty} {{n-1} \choose {12-1}}\cdot  0.448419^{12}\cdot (1- 0.448419)^{n-12}=0.915083\approx 91.51\%$$

**Remark**

For **(c)** you can also use the converse proability $P(X\geq 20)=1-P(X\leq 19)$

$$1-\sum_{n=12}^{19} {{n-1} \choose {12-1}}\cdot  0.448419^{12}\cdot (1- 0.448419)^{n-12}$$

$$=1-0.084917=0.915083\approx 91.51\%$$